# Material Chip Margin Top does nothing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-chips

I have a `ChipGroup` and two chips inside it. I am trying to add `marginTop` to the chips but they are stacked on the top of the `ChipGroup`. The `marginStart` is working as expected but the `marginTop` does nothing.

[image]

Here is my xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="33dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chip_1"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"
            android:layout_width="92dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Test"
            app:chipCornerRadius="5dp"
            app:chipMinTouchTargetSize="0dp"
            app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_close"
            app:closeIconSize="10dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            android:id="@+id/chip_2"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"
            android:layout_width="92dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Test"
            app:chipCornerRadius="5dp"
            app:chipMinTouchTargetSize="0dp"
            app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_close"
            app:closeIconSize="10dp" />
 </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

Comment: why don't you set margin to chipgroup ?

Comment: @Bhavnik because that moves the whole chipgroup. I just want the chips to have margin top from the chipgroup and not to be stack οn the top of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution.

[image]

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
    android:id="@+id/chipGroup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dp_15"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/chip_1"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_50"
        android:text="Test"
        app:chipCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:chipMinTouchTargetSize="0dp"
        app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_close"
        app:closeIconSize="10dp" />

    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/chip_2"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Entry"
        android:layout_width="92dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_5"
        android:text="Test"
        app:chipCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:chipMinTouchTargetSize="0dp"
        app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_close"
        app:closeIconSize="10dp" />
</com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>
```

Comment: Padding top in the chipgroup was the solution Thank you!